# jquery-timepicker auto correction not seen during angularjs post.

Tags: jquery, angularjs

I'm using jquery-timepicker v1.8.7 with angularjs which almost works perfectly with the exception of the auto correction. If I manually type into the field say 815 it will auto correct to you 8:15 AM which is perfect, however when I submit the angularjs form, only the original value 815 is submitted. Any idea how to address this issue?

My directive

```
.directive('xpTimepicker', timepicker);

function timepicker() {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link : function(scope, element, attrs) {
            element.timepicker({
                'step': 15,
                'timeFormat': 'g:i A'
            });

        }
    };
}
```

html

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="startTime" 
placeholder="Work Start Time" format ng-model="formData.scheduleStartTime" xp-timepicker required >
```

Comment: will need to `require` ngModel controller in directive and modify `$modelValue` within events callbacks of plugin

Comment: might also find an angular wrapper module for this plugin. Alternative would be find an angular timepicker

Comment: @charlietfl could you provide an example?